# Google sheet api integration geetin error like InterruptedException

Tags: android, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

i want to integrate google sheet api in my application so i use following link 
https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/android and i follow all steps for that and i want to call spreadsheet below link

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17Rdom3QF21uTbp89ZTXqjL8CmUGyoCvxJ5Hnc7wVqjk/edit#gid=0

I change my code as per below function

```
private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
        String spreadsheetId = "17Rdom3QF21uTbp89ZTXqjL8CmUGyoCvxJ5Hnc7wVqjk";
        String range = "Sheet1!B:D";
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        ValueRange response = this.mService.spreadsheets().values()
                .get(spreadsheetId, range)
                .execute();
        List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
        if (values != null) {
            results.add("Category2, Category4");
            for (List row : values) {
                results.add(row.get(1) + ", " + row.get(3));
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
```

When i run above code i get output in textview like **Invalid index 3 , size is 3**  any idea how can i solve this ? your all suggestions are appreciable

**LOGCAT**

```
java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1280)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:219)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:82)
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:295)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerCancel(FutureTask.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.cancel(FutureTask.java:75)
at android.os.AsyncTask.cancel(AsyncTask.java:467)
at pkg.android.srtpl.googlespreadsheetdemo.NewMain$MakeRequestTask.doInBackground(NewMain.java:346)
at pkg.android.srtpl.googlespreadsheetdemo.NewMain$MakeRequestTask.doInBackground(NewMain.java:323)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

[image]

Comment: Please paste the full error stacktrace.

Comment: Is this "Invalid index 3 , size is 3" in an exception or displayed on your app? Looks like exception text, but it's not in the trace you posted. Is there more on that stacktrace? Sometimes the answer lies further down it.

Comment: Karen Forde : check my screen shot i get following output when i run my code

Comment: You may getting the error because you are trying to fetch a null value. Try using `row.size()` if you are getting the last column that has a value instead of hard coded to prevent such error. Hope this helps!

Comment: Mr.Rebot : can you post code sample so i can get idea where i have to change in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me too, really weird. Not the best but it worked for me

```
for(int i=0;i<values.size();i++){
    List row = values.get(i);
    for(int j=0;j<row.size();j++){
        results.add(row.get(j)+",");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by ensuring there was data in each cell.