# Sheet API invalid index 1, size is 1

Tags: android, google-sheets-api

I have this error when i try my code :

```
 private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
        String spreadsheetId = "1UV816hTkiUo6NLrsqAKgG0VjnSvKwcBB5-iZGX-V8E0";
        String range = "Feuille 1!B3:C";
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        ValueRange response = this.mService.spreadsheets().values()
                .get(spreadsheetId, range)
                .execute();
        List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
        if (values != null) {
            results.add("Intitule, Status");
            for (List row : values) {
                results.add(row.get(0) + ", " + row.get(1));
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
```

This code is from [Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/android) and when i Copy and test it works. But i just change the spreadhseet id and the range, dont know why i have this error.

here's a screen of my spreedsheetv[image]

As you can see i would like to retrieve something like

```
 some value, OK
 some value, OK
 some value, NON OK
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok Google Sheet Api fail reading if one rows is blank, and consider the size as wrong.

Still dont know how to fix this, but this is why i have this error, just have to fill all my grid. (the photo is just a part of my whole grid)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to replicate your issue and I also got an error when I have a blank row or cell.

See screenshot:

[image]

Basically, error **invalid index 1, size is 1** indicates that you are trying to fetch a `null` value. *Try using `row.size()` if you are getting the last column that has a value instead of hard coded to prevent such error.* So I suggest to ensure that there are data in each cell. ([Source.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38242619/google-sheet-api-integration-geetin-error-like-interruptedexception))